# The Yamaha LS9-16

Tags: digidesign, 003

Hi there,

Has anyone used the Yamaha LS9-16 in harmony with Protools LE 9? Have been asked to shop around to compare prices with the DigiDesign 003 and see which works better with Protools LE 9. My initial thought is that the 003 is a perfect match considering the fact that it is made to work with Protools but I need to find out about the Yamaha. How do the 2 compare when recording and mixing down? Price wise, I did research and found the LS9 to be considerable more expensive. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it does not work well with PT.  It is a LIVE console, not a studio console, so it's really not designed to be a control surface.  It's also VERY expensive and there are a lot of other options out there.

Have you look at the Presonus StudioLive products?  They are relatively cheap and a nice surface.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested to hear what you are planning to use the LS9 for. Or more precisely why you were asked to compare the two. As others have said, the digi003 by itself is far less expensive.

If you are going to spend the 10k on a controller, why not just get the digidesign C24? The 003 is made to go with PT.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I was asked to get info on the LS9 as a possible replacement for the 003 by a non-audio person who runs the finance. I knew he was wrong but needed back up to my argument. I agree with you and we ordered the 003 for our small studio's since they are perfect for PT Thanks for the response. +1

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak for the Yamaha, but I did notice that between my 002 versus my 828mkIII, the 828 under core audio was much more stable... used a percent or two more CPU, but the meter was consistent - under the 002 I was getting all sorts of weird spikes... That was back at v9.0... haven't tried the 002 with the 9.0.3 update.